# MVC Html.ActionLink removes empty querystring parameter from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, parameters, query-string, actionlink

I'm using the `Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues)` overload to send some params to an Action Method..

Sometimes I need to pass an empty parameter value like: `?item1=&item2=value`

I'm specifying the param in the anonymous type I create and pass as `routeValues`, but both `null` and `string.Empty` result in a URL that omits the empty `item1` param.

```
new { item1 = null, item2 = "value" } 
new { item1 = string.Empty, item2 = "value" }
new { item1 = "", item2 = "value" }

// all result in:
?item2=value
```

I can create the URL manually but I want to use the helper method.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an `EmptyParameter` class as follows:

```
public class EmptyParameter
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action",
                 "Controller",
                  new { item1 = new EmptyParameter(), item2 = "value" });
```

Comment: I haven't tried this and I already changed the code to create the link manually, but I'm going to accept this since you seem to know exactly how to fix it and you were lightning fast! :D

Comment: I did try it and it does seem to generate `item1=&item2=value`. Thanks.

Comment: Since the `ToString()` implementation for DBNull is defined to return `String.Empty` you can alternatively use `DBNull.Value` and avoid the need to define the `EmptyParameter` class.

Comment: Why the heck the .Net team removes empty values inside `RouteCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea(HttpContext,string)`? What's the reason? Anyway thanx, excellent solution! i was losing an entire day behind this.

Comment: @ChristopherKing better use `UrlParameter.Optional` since is more related than `DBNull.Value` and is less confusing